how do i find from which object the cut is made from?
There's a bottle model.

It has various cuts named as imprints. Below are the cuts made from the bottle.

In 3D view, I know the cuts are drawn from the 100002-bottle object. But, I want to find this from scripting. How to find from which object the cut is drawn through scripting?
Any help is appreciated.

Loop through all objects to find that it has a Boolean modifier for a specific object
# select one object in object mode first

import bpy


def find_objects_used_boolean(active_object):
    lis = []
    for ob in bpy.data.objects:
        if hasattr(ob, "modifiers"):
            if ob.modifiers:
                for md in ob.modifiers:
                    if md.type == "BOOLEAN":
                        if md.object == active_object:
                            lis.append(ob)

    return lis


lis = find_objects_used_boolean(bpy.context.object)
print(lis)

